# Union of an intersection of an indexed family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking at $A_{n,k} = \left[{n \over k}, nk\right], n,k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ and trying to find $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{n,k}$.

I start off with $\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{n,k}$. The "smallest" set $\left[{n \over k}, nk\right]$ is $A_{n,1}=\{n\}$ and all the other sets defined that way ($n$ constant and $k$ chosen freely) include $n$. I conclude $\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{n,k} = \{n\}$.

It immediately follows that $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \{n\} = \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$.

I haven't had much experience with infinite unions and intersections of indexed families of sets, so I would appreciate any remarks on my approach.

Comment: Nothing to add here. Good job!